# A tool to create regular expressions that apply to a set of URLs?

Tags: regex, url

Is there a webapp or other tool that can "read" a given set of URLs, and return regex that applies to all? I would ideally hope that it returns the "lowest common" pattern so that I can use the resulting regex to filter for the given set of URLs *plus* other similar URLs.

Bonus feature: An even more precise tool with 2 input fields: 1 for URLs that the user would like to be captured by the regex, and another field for URLs that would not apply. This feature would thereby further narrow the resulting regular expression.

A tool like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is helpful, but it necessitates lots of trial and error for a regex rookie like me. Is there a tool that's even more noob friendly?

Comment: This would be nigh impossible because there's almost an infinite amount of possibilities that can be done with a url, and any regex given would be very messy. Learn the basics of regex, it'll go a long way!

Comment: Producing a matching regex is fairly simple: escape the URIs and use *or* sequences: `((uri1)|(uri2)|uri3))`.

Comment: @ComFreek that's a good point. I think what I'm looking for is a program that spits out regex a little "smarter" than that. I'd want the regex to be as broad as possible, while still defining the specified URLs. I should probably edit my question to include this specification.